# Browser to Server API Request/Response

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, authorization, fetch-api

I’m currently looking to integrate 2 strict security systems that require oauth2.0 authentication. I am looking to submit data from one system to the other which will be triggered when the users presses a button.

I just wanted to confirm this would be the best practice and see if there was any solutions I was over looking!

The first system, which is making the API call, I only have access to the front end which is using js. I am also only able to perform post requests to the endpoint, this becomes a problem with the second system.

The second system requires a login from the user and then confirmation from the user that the data can be exchanged. The issue is once the login prompt has been complete it issues a get request to system 1s endpoint, which is blocked, and I can’t do anything about it. The site is strict around CORs but I have done some testing connecting via the cors.anywhere proxy hosted locally which appears to avoid the CORs issue.

I was considering creating my own proxy server which I would:

- Issue the authorisation request to the proxy server + transfer the data
- open the login prompt for the user to enter their credentials/confirm data exchange (I'm not sure if this would even be possible?)
- return authorisation code to the proxy server
- proxy server then sends a request for the access token using the authorisation code
- data submitted to the relevant endpoint using the token

## Any suggestions would be welcomed and if I do need to create a proxy server, any recommendations on solutions would be great!

I’ve tried using a fetch in system 1 to open the authorisation endpoint but unfortunately I was not able to get the authorisation code, I may be missing something obvious here.